# How to fix Expected a value of type '((Json, Json) => int)?', but got one of type '(dynamic, dynamic) => dynamic'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am trying to make my list of Jsons in descending order by expiration date. I am getting this error:

> Expected a value of type '((TimelineJson, TimelineJson) => int)?', but got one of type '(dynamic,
> dynamic) => dynamic'

This is my method to sort the list:

```dart
void downloadtimeline(String job) {
  timelinelist.sort((a, b) {
    var adate = a['downloadUrlExpiration'];
    var bdate = b['downloadUrlExpiration'];
    return adate.compareTo(bdate);
  });
```

This is the handling of JSON file:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

List<TimelineJson> welcomeFromJson(String str) => List<TimelineJson>.from(
    json.decode(str).map((x) => TimelineJson.fromJson(x)));

String welcomeToJson(List<TimelineJson> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class TimelineJson {
  TimelineJson({
    this.requestId,
    this.job,
    this.customer,
    this.requested,
    this.processed,
    this.downloadUrl,
    this.downloadUrlExpiration,
  });

  int? requestId;
  String? job;
  String? customer;
  DateTime? requested;
  DateTime? processed;
  String? downloadUrl;
  DateTime? downloadUrlExpiration;

  factory TimelineJson.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => TimelineJson(
    requestId: json["request_id"],
    job: json["job"],
    customer: json["customer"],
    requested: DateTime.parse(json["requested"]),
    processed: DateTime.parse(json["processed"]),
    downloadUrl: json["download_url"],
    downloadUrlExpiration: DateTime.parse(json["download_url_expiration"]),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "request_id": requestId,
    "job": job,
    "customer": customer,
    "requested": requested?.toIso8601String(),
    "processed": processed?.toIso8601String(),
    "download_url": downloadUrl,
    "download_url_expiration": downloadUrlExpiration?.toIso8601String(),
  };
}
```

The list works fine its just throwing the error when I want to sort it by experationdate.

Comment: Where have you defined `timelinelist`? And what type have you used? I have a suspicion you have just written `List` instead of `List<TimelineJson>`. Otherwise, try replace `timelinelist.sort((a, b) {` with `timelinelist.sort((TimelineJson a, TimelineJson b) {`

Comment: Timelinelist is a global variable defined as late var timelinelist and it has worked for displaying information so far. after switching var in the sort method with Timelinejson it says compareTo isnt defined

Comment: Well, yeah. You need to define how you want to compare the two `TimelineJson` objects. If you are going to compare just a field of each, then use that (but remember to handle what should happen in case of `null`).

Comment: Also wait a minute. Why are `timelinelist` not a list of `TimelineJson` objects? Are you saying it is a list of `Map<String, dynamic>`?

Comment: Yes it is being filled by a API connection and get requests to fill the lists.